# Save last elements from deep nested object to a non global array

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, object, nested

I already found out, how to get the last elements of a deep nested object.
See here for working example: [How to get the last children in a deeply nested array with objects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56756192/how-to-get-the-last-children-in-a-deeply-nested-array-with-objects)

Now I dont want to log the names like in the example with `console.log(subObj.name)`, instead I want to save them in an array, which **shouldnt be global**. I just want a function return this array.
Is this somehow possible without declaring a global array for this ?

This is my code:

```
 function childrenNames (obj) {
        var lastChildren = [];
        obj.forEach((subObj) => {
            if (subObj.hasOwnProperty('specification') && subObj.specification instanceof Array && subObj.specification.length > 0) {
                childrenNames(subObj.specification);
            } else {
                if (subObj.hasOwnProperty('name')) {
                    lastChildren.push(subObj.name)
                }
            }
        })
        console.log(lastChildren);
        return lastChildren
    }
```

But its just returning 4 different arrays instead of 1 containing all last children.

Comment: Create a new array at the beginning of the function, add to that array (instead of logging), return that array at the end of the function.

Comment: @Ouroborus Are you sure this is working? Because its a recursive function and Im always getting 3+ different Arrays returned. I want just one containing all of the names.

Comment: Without your code (with your changes) there's no way to tell what's wrong.

Comment: @Ouroborus I added my code above

Answer (score -1):

I am not sure whether this is a valid answer and I do not understand it but I am leaving it for now because it does appear, superficially at least, to answer the question. It does not require a global array to be declared as far as I can tell?

```js
var obj = [
 {
  name: 'something',
  children: [
   {
    name: 'something',
    children: [
     {
      name: 'no child'
     },
     {
      name: 'something empty',
      children: [ ]
     }
    ]
   }
  ]
 },
 {
  name: 'something',
  children: [
   {
    name: 'something',
    children: [
     {
      name: 'no child'
     }
    ]
   }
  ]
 },
 {
    name: "children isn't an array",
    children: 42
 }
]

function childrenNames (obj) {
  var lastChildren = [];
  obj.forEach((subObj) => {
      if (subObj.hasOwnProperty('specification') && subObj.specification instanceof Array && subObj.specification.length > 0) {
          childrenNames(subObj.specification);
      } else {
          if (subObj.hasOwnProperty('name')) {
              lastChildren.push(subObj.name)
          }
      }
  })
  // console.log(lastChildren);
  return lastChildren
}

const res = childrenNames(obj);

console.log('res', res);
```

Comment: @Bergi Do you think this is an acceptable answer? From the point of view of not being global

Comment: Hey, could you please explain what the wrapper is doing here? I wonder because the function is not being called

Comment: I will try and explain what I think it is doing by editing the answer so it is together with the code.

Comment: @testerprox I am now completely confused. I thought I was calling `const res = wrapper(childrensNames, obj);` but looking at the snippet I am not calling wrapper anywhere. I can not understand why childrensNames is running as it is not being called let alone why it *seems* to be working. Sorry for the confusion!

Comment: I am totally confused and will change my answer?!